# TabLayout set tab background states programmatically

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-design-library

I'm trying to set a background on custom views inside a `TabLayout`, with different states, through code.

There's a couple of questions with similar title, but they deal with XML.

As far as I can tell, `mTabBackgroundResId` is set through XML only, and is applied to a `TabView` upon creation. However, since I'm using custom views, it doesn't apply. Setting a background on the custom view through code or in XML will only result in something like this:

[image]

Comment: You can access the `TabView` instance with `tabLayout.getTabAt(position).getCustomView()`

Comment: @NileshSingh same result as pictured above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MyTabLayout extends TabLayout {
    private LinearLayout linearLayout;

    private void init(Context context, attrs etc.) {
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) getChildAt(0);
    }

    private StateListDrawable getStateListDrawable() {
        StateListDrawable sld = new StateListDrawable();
        sld.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},
            ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, <color_id>);
        sld.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_selected},
            ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, <color_id>);
        sld.addState(new int[] { },
            ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, <color_id>);
        return sld;
    }

    public void addTab(String label) {
        addTab(newTab().setCustomView(<view> or <view_id>);
        linearLayout.getChildAt(linearLayout.getChildCount()-1)
            .setBackground(getStateListDrawable());
    }
}
```